# Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers

Tags: php, apache, output-buffering, ob-start

I've reinstalled Apache, and switched from PHP 5.3 to 5.6. Everything works, except I get this error, when calling `ob_start()`:

```
Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers
```

I tried to enable output buffering in PHP, but I still get this error:

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

Comment: Whats the memory limit in the used php.ini, i think if you set it to a higher value it will work.

Comment: The memory_limit in php.ini? It's 1024M at the moment

Comment: That should be enough! Is it a custom site or wordpress?

Comment: Do you output the buffer in the `ob_start` callback?

Comment: Can you provide us with a little more information of where and how you are using the ob_start?

Comment: We replace every `{{TEXTID}}` string in the output to the appropriate text

Comment: can you add that bit of code to the question so we can see it? like Alex said do you output the buffer in the callback, or are you actually using a callback for the ob_start

Comment: I use a callback function

Comment: please copy all the code thats causing the error, now we're missing a lot of information that we can use to fix the error, replace sensitive data with ******, there's no context for us to work with. you're saying ob_start causes the bug, but i can tell you that's not the problem, it's the callback function that has the error.

Comment: maybe interesting? [ob_get_status — Get status of output buffers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-status.php)

Comment: can u post exact log enteries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are using a buffering function in output buffering callback which isn't possible as mentioned in php ob_start [output_callback](http://php.net/ob_start) documentation. If not it should be the output-handler you used, check your php.ini and try to set it's value to "none" if possible.

Answer (score 10):

You're trying to start a output buffer inside a buffer callback. If you use this code, it will generate that error. But if you remove the `ob_start()` from the callback function it's OK.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

function callback($buffer){
    //you can't call ob_start here
    ob_start();
    return (str_replace("apples", "oranges", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");

?>
<html>
<body>
<p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 6):

Even though this is an old question, I just wanted to add that the same error occurs when the system runs out of memory while buffering.

If this is the case, the error mentioned in this topic will always be followed by an `Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted` error.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this sample code can help you:

```
ob_start();
echo "test";
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
var_dump($content);
```