# Error : ob_start(): Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I am facing below issue on nginx using php5-fpm. I tried to find out solution but didn't find anything.

> 2016/02/18 13:58:27 [error] 12256#0: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  ob_start(): **Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in system/core/Exceptions.php on line 166**"

My project is implemented using the CodeIgniter Web Framework.

**Environment:**
Server: nginx 
PHP   : php5-fpm 5.3

Comment: what's the code causing the error? (plus: multiple exclamation marks are impolite)

Comment: When trying to upload image or  captcha image generating for example please see the below url when I am accessing this captcha image not generating showing below above error in error log.
Url : http://m.fitbudz.com/sign/up

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936067/cannot-use-output-buffering-in-output-buffering-display-handlers

Comment: Added relevant tags, minor language fixes, reformat code for readability

Comment: I have already tried this option but still getting same issue.