# PHP automatically pre- and append dynamic content to output

Tags: php

Is there a way to automatically include content before and after the actual output of a file?

Why? For example to use this to include everything up to the main content (dynamcally generated HTML, head, opening tags...) and after the file runs, automatically close everything up again.

I know of the `ob_start` approach, but I'm not sure if dynamically generated content is easy to include that way:

```
<?php
function bootstrap_page($content) {
    return "text before" . $content . "text after";
}

ob_start(bootstrap_page);
?>
```

But then, `ob` cannot be used to capture the output of an include within the callback, AFAIK. So that makes it hard to easily pre- and append something dynamically generated. I could use long strings in the callback function to get a static version working - but is there a way to do this more seamlessly?

In other words I'm basically trying to include a php file before and one after any (other) file I need and that - if possible reduced to a function call at the start of a given file.

The functionality I'm looking for would transform this:

```
<?php
bootstrap_this();
?>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

before.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <?php include('head.php'); ?>
  <body>
    <?php if(somecondition) { ?>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <?php } ?>
```

after.php:

```
  </body>
</html>
```

Into something like this:

```
<?php
include 'before.php';
?>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<?php
include 'after.php';
?>
```

And in the end into:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <?php include('head.php'); ?>
  <body>
    <?php if(somecondition) { ?>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <?php } ?>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a framework or at least a templating engine. Why would you write raw PHP?

Comment: @ryantxr idk -  just to suffer? I got away without one so far - but if there is not an easy way to achieve it, I may have to.

Comment: I really don't understand. You want to know how to include some value to prepend and append to a content string to a function that is not hard-coded as your example demonstrates ("text before") ("text after")?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld maybe I wasn't clear enough - I'll try to update my question. I'm basically trying to include a php file before and one after any (other) file I need. The function shown does something like that, but with just strings.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332262/how-do-i-prepend-file-to-beginning (Maybe answer from Alex?)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld no, because it's just the file content - it needs to be run. I've updated my question, maybe it's a bit clearer now what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I've added an answer but I'm not sure if I got it.

Comment: Use output buffers as you mentioned. I think it's the only way. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld thanks for you effort. Yes, it seems like you can't sandwich the output out the current file easily. This would also have to be run from another file.

Comment: My last update2 might give you a hint/clue how you oould create what you want to create. This is generally not something you code yourself :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld thank you! I does what I asked, but It makes my code more complicated than before, so I'll probably still have to opt for the not coding myself option and use some kind of framework. ;)

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to help you ... to figure out you should not code this yourself ;-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld you might have given me an idea though. I'll try that and maybe I can provide an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @bestprogrammerintheworld, I came up with this:

```
function use_template($before = 'pre', $after = 'post') {
    ob_start();
    include $before . '.php';
    $pre = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    ob_start();
    include $after . '.php';
    $post = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $bootstrap_page = function ($content) use ($pre, $post) {
        return $pre . $content . $post;
    };

    ob_start($bootstrap_page);
}
```

If this function is called a the beginning of a php file, the outputs of `before.php` and `after.php` get stored and bound to the callback. Then, after all the main output is read, everything is pieced together. No code at the end of the file required.

Since `ob` cannot be run within the callback, `bootstrap_page`, it must be run beforehand to capture the other files first.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld thanks for your help - I could make it work!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that what output buffering is for?

```
<?php
// Start Buffer
ob_start();

// Include before
include 'before.php'; 
?>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<?php
// Include after
include 'after.php';

// Get buffered output
$page = ob_get_clean();

echo $page;
?>
```

Comment: I think OP knew this, but IMO OP was looking for a way to make a function out of this where before, content and after is  the included files.

Comment: In that case your answer is a possible approach.

Comment: @davidgiesemann yes, i knew this. I'm basically trying to sandwich the output of a php file between the output of two other ones (or even better: at a given point in one file) by calling a function at the start of the file to be sandwiched. Basically a poor mans template engine.

Answer (score 1):

> But then, ob cannot be used to capture the output of an include within the callback, AFAIK

AFAYK ? Would it be hard to test? As long as the include is after ob_start() and the code does not explicitly call ob_flush() before you choose to do so, then it will capture the output.

> I'm basically trying to include a php file before and one after any (other) file I need

That implies some set sort of controlling script which calls the pre-oinclude, the main content and the post-include.

That would be OK if HTML (not true, I'll come back to that) did not have a defined root which should be explicitly declared.  And you have the issue HTTP also has a structure which you risk subverting here - headers come before content. But leaving those aside for now, HTML requires a nested structure. All tags should be closed. Opening and closing tags in different files is messy and bad practice.

There are a whole lot technologies which provide the end result you appear to be looking for - ESI, templating and front-controller patterns all provide this in a much more structured way.

Comment: No, in fact I did test it - I just wasn't sure if I did it right. But it lead to: `ob_start(): Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936067/cannot-use-output-buffering-in-output-buffering-display-handlers

Comment: And: technically, it could be done in the same file - I just explained it like that for simplicity.

Comment: I already found that question. That's part of the reason I asked if there is another way to achieve this. If I understood correctly, it's impossible to use `ob` in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I see the usage of this or if I understood this correct, but if I understood it correctly you're looking for something like this:

```
<?php
function dynamice_include($before, $content, $after) {
    $dynamic_content = '';
    $dynamic_content .= include $before . '.php';
    $dynamic_content .= $content;
    $dynamic_content .= include $after . '.php';
    return $dynamic_content;
}
```

Usage:

```
$content = dynamice_include('before', 'Hello I am really cool','after');
echo $content;
```

In before.php and after.php a return would be required, e.g.

```
before.php
<?php
return "wow before";

after.php
<?php
return "wow after";
```

and the result would be:

```
wow beforeHello I am really coolwow after
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems it more something like this you're looking for. output-buffers are the only way AFAIK to achieve this.

This code is not optimized at all... (I just show the concept here)

```
<?php
function dynamice_include($before, $content, $after) {
    $dynamic_content = '';

    ob_start();
    include $before . '.php';
    $dynamic_content .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();  

    ob_start();
    include $content . '.php';
    $dynamic_content .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();  

    ob_start();
    include $after . '.php';
    $dynamic_content .= ob_get_contents();    
    ob_end_clean();  

    return $dynamic_content;
}

$content = dynamice_include('before', 'dytest','after');
echo $content;
```

As other stated though - it's a lot of platforms, frameworks, template engines out there that could solve this issue. You will have do ob_start() and ob_clean within the current files content for this to work.

**UPDATE2:**

In this case I fetch current files output buffer as content.

```
<?php
function dynamice_include($before, $content, $after) {
    $dynamic_content = '';

    ob_start();
    include $before . '.php';
    $dynamic_content .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();  

    $dynamic_content .= $content;

    ob_start();
    include $after . '.php';
    $dynamic_content .= ob_get_contents();    
    ob_end_clean();  

    return $dynamic_content;
}
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    feelings    
</body>
</html>
<?php
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$content = dynamice_include('before', $content, 'after');
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: pretty much, except `$content`  is the captured output of a file. Wait - It's possible to run an get the output in the form of a string with include? If that's the case, my question was useless...

Comment: Oh I see - no `before.php` and `after.php` contain html with some php and not just strings, so I can't really return it.

Comment: Just get a files content with file_get_contents(), e.g. $str = file_get_contents($file);

Comment: @but it's not a static html file - it contains some php code that inserts some information and decides which parts are rendered. I'll try to update my question with a simple example...